# Why doesn't using grep -r -e filename find files named "filename"?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I want to search k1.sh,  in all folders of my directory

```
ADU-07 WebInterface-JobTable_files
ADU-07 WebInterface-JobTable.html
ADU-07 WebInterface-SelfTestResults_files
ADU-07 WebInterface-SelfTestResults.html
meas_2016-07-13_20-22-00
meas_2016-07-13_20-25-13
meas_2016-07-13_20-29-43
meas_2016-07-13_20-33-43
meas_2016-07-13_20-37-43
meas_2016-07-13_20-54-43
meas_2016-07-13_21-46-43
```

When I try

```
grep -r -e "k1.sh"  /home/milenko/SerradoMel/MT06
```

I got nothing.Why? How to check if my grep supports -r option?

Comment: I think if you use `-e` to designate the expression, then you have to use `-f` to designate the file.  I don't generally use either switch.  Try `grep -r "k1.sh" /home/milenko/...`

Comment: If it didn't support `-r`, it would be throwing an error. Can you add the output of a `grep` with one of these filenames explicitly passed that *does* show that it matches content within that file?

Comment: @JuanTomas, ...no, `-e` and `-r` do not conflict in the manner proposed.

Comment: Do you want to find all files named `k1.sh` or do you want to find the string `k1.sh` inside all files?

Comment: @JuanTomas: No; you can specify `-e 'regex'` without needing `-f file'`.

Comment: (...if you're trying to find a file **named** `k1.sh`, that's not a job for a recursive `grep` at all, but a job for the `find` command, as `grep` is looking at files' contents, not their names -- hence my eariler request for you to amend the question to show that `k1.sh` really does match *content within* one of the files).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Hmm,I see,will try with find,but it is strange grep can not find named file.

Comment: @RichardRublev, of course it can find the file, but it won't report it in its output unless the file **contains** content that matches the regular expression `k1.sh` in its output, because that's what `grep`'s purpose is: Finding file **contents**, not file **names**.

Comment: @PauloScardine All files named k1.sh,will try with find.

Comment: The GNU guys screwed up when they gave GNU grep the ability to find files recursively. What's next, an option to sort it's output? Forget you ever heard of `-r` or anything else related to finding files with grep and use the tool that is designed to find files - the somewhat obviously named `find`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` checks files' contents, not files' names. You can test this like so:

```
mkdir -p foo.d
echo "non-matching" >foo.d/k1.sh
echo "k1.sh"        >foo.d/matching
grep -r -e k1.sh foo.d
rm -rf -- foo.d
```

The output of the above is:

```
foo.d/matching:k1.sh
```

...where `foo.d/matching` is the filename which was matched, and `k1.sh` is the content.

You'll see that it doesn't identify the file named `k1.sh` (but having the contents `non-matching`), but instead identifies the file named `matching`; this is because the documented purpose of `grep` is to look at files' contents, not files' names.

---

Instead, to find a file named `k1.sh`, use:

```
find /home/milenko/SerradoMel/MT06 -type f -name k1.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: Do you want to find all files named k1.sh or do you want to find the string k1.sh inside all files?
>
> **Answer**: @PauloScardine All files named k1.sh,will try with find.

Then grep is the wrong guy for the job. The grep command looks for the string "k1.sh" inside all files in that path - if you want to find all files named "k1.sh" you are looking for the `find` command instead:

```
find /home/milenko/SerradoMel/MT06 -name k1.sh
```